# Error on jquery fade in after using stop

Tags: jquery, callback, fadein

I'm new on jquery and i needed to do a chaining of effects on different elements so i used the callback functions like this example:

HTML:

```
<div id="div1" class="class1">hello</div>
<div id="div2" class="class2">world</div>
<div id="div3" class="class3"></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#div1").fadeIn(1000,
(function(){
   $("#div2").fadeIn(5000,
   (function(){ 
     $("#div3").fadeIn(1000);
   });
 });
```

so if i want to stop it at any point i call a function that goes something like this:

```
$(".class1").stop(true);
$(".class2").stop(true);
$(".class3").stop(true);
```

(don't know if there's a better way to do this)

but the most important problem is that sometimes and i dont know why if i do the animations again the image fading in wont do it complete anymore. So what i'm asking is if i'm doing something wrong with these two codes that is causing the error

Comment: Is this your actual code? There are mismatched parentheses before your anonymous functions.

Comment: make a fiddle of it please / show html/css & events bindings

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi no this was just an example code i did fast for the post

Answer (score 0):

[fadeIn() documantation about usage](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and your sample should be like this:

```
$(".class1").stop().fadeIn(1000,function(){
   $(".class2").fadeIn(5000,function(){ 
     $(".class3").fadeIn(1000);
   });
});
```

or alternate way for you:

```
$(".class1").stop().fadeIn(1000);
$(".class2").delay(1000).stop().fadeIn(5000);
$(".class3").delay(5000).stop().fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: the first sample does not stop the callback functions, i guess it's because im fading different elements, it stop the class1 but not the others, i think